# Использование system("pause")

Tags: c++

Существует проблема, которую не могу уже решить дня 2 минимум. Чем объявлять `system("pause")` в C++? Пробовал и `<windows>`, и `<stdlib>`, и `<conio.h>`, весь гугл обшарил, даже на `getchar()` пробовал заменить `system`, но после отладки проги консоль в упор закрывается :(

Comment: М-м-да... Смешать **<stdlib.h>** и **<cstdlib>**... Это надо еще уметь... Напишите что-то одно из них, и ставьте *system("pause")*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Внимание!** Правильный ответ на вопрос [был уже дан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/636992/240512) пользователем [Андрей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/239665/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9): функция `system` объявлена в заголовочном файле `cstdlib` (или `stdlib.h`). Пожалуйста, не добавляйте новых ответов вида "*я подключил N и все заработало*", где N - очередной заголовок, косвенно включающий cstdlib.

---

В `Microsoft Visual Studio`, например, при запуске по <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, IDE сама будет запускать программу, как будто бы в ней ожидается ввод в конце.

*Еще варианты решения:*

- `MS-овская` функция `_getch()` из `<conio.h>`
- `std::cin >> c`, где `c` - это `char c`. Правда, придется нажимать еще и `enter`.
- `Breakpoint` на закрывающей скобке `int main(...) { }`.
- *Можно еще что-нибудь придумать.*

Answer (score 19):

Прекратите заниматься ерундой с вписыванием в код каких-то `system("pause")` и прочего мусора. Ничего подобного в консольном приложении быть не должно.

Если вы занимаетесь разработкой консольного приложения под MS Visual Studio, то идите в настройки проекта, раздел `Linker` и установите настройку `SubSystem` в значение `CONSOLE`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего возьмите в привычку запускать свое приложение не в отладочном режиме ("Start Debugging", F5), а в режиме "без отладчика" ("Start Without Debugging", Ctrl+F5). Консольное окно в таком случае не будет закрываться само, а будет оставаться на экране до следующего нажатия клавиши.

Запуск же программ под отладчиком (F5) предназначен для ситуаций, когда у вас в коде есть точки останова, т.е. при запуске под отладчиком вас проблема автоматического закрытия окна волновать не должна вообще.

---

В VS2017, начиная с определенной версии, появилась опция отладчика, которая предотвращает закрытие консольного окна по завершении программы, независимо от того, запускали ли вы вашу программу в режиме отладки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8):

Нужно подключать библиотеку `cstdlib`, т.к. `system` объявлена в ней.

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/147738)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вызов `getchar()` не срабатывает из-за того, что в буфере ввода уже есть некий символ. Обычно это перевод строки, оставшийся от `scanf`. Поэтому надо прочитать сначала его, а уже потом ещё один, который нажмёт пользователь:

```
getchar(), getchar();
```

Ну и естественно, это дело надо удалить, как только оно перестанет быть нужным.

PS: Если при вводе пользователь перед enter'ом нажмёт пробел, то всё равно не сработает.

Answer (score -1):

```
//попробуй так-действие тожесамое
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
...
cout << "Для продолжения нажмите Enter\n";
cin.get();//можно несколько раз, для верности
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

если builder то
`#include <iostream.h>`

Comment: что-то не работает замена скобок:
#include (iostream.h) вместо () поставьте нормальные скобки.

Comment: `system` должна находиться не там. Хотя про билдер не в курсе.

Answer (score -4):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Как же вы товарищ самую стандартную библиотеку iostream -то не попробовали??? Она ещё cin cout и cerr позволяет использовать (может вы не знаете), а глядя на подсказки интеллисенса (он для C++ появился в VS2012) у неё вообще много чего есть (вернее конкретно в std).
PS: для новичков: студийную библиотеку надо подключать в коде после не-студийных, а то так и будет писать типа "переменная system не найдена ..." - сами виноваты. Это ведь C++ ёкарный бабай.

Answer (score -6):

попробуй Директиву `#include<stdio.h>`
и вставь `system("pause\n");`
Для оператора `getch();` директива `#include <conio.h>!`

Comment: `system` не должна находиться в `stdio.h`. Даже не знаю, в VS может такое сработать или нет, но в других - точно нет.

Answer (score -8):

У меня такая проблема решилась вот так

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   cout << "После выполнения, вaс ожидает пауза" << endl;

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Т.е. нужно добавить входные аргументы для функции main(), а именно

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
}
```

Comment: Это может сработать только в VS, да и то не факт, что во всех версиях.