# Не могу записать числовые данные в текстовый файл

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему я могу считывать данные с файла, но значения переменных dblx, dblResult не записываются в файл. Не могу найти ошибку. Заранее спасибо за помощь. 
[текстовый файл](https://mega.nz/#!s7AnzLya!sE-JTpyGEOpqvq87PMId-5yOSU31eSNL9EttJMhrXmg)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    double dbla, dblb, dbld, dblx, dblResult;
    int ic;
    fstream stream;
    stream.open("data.txt", ios::app | ios::out);
    if (!stream) 
    {
        cout << "Error while opening file";
        Sleep(2000);
        exit(1);
    }

    stream >> dbla;
    stream >> dblb;
    stream >> ic;
    stream >> dbld;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the value of variable x : ";
        cin >> dblx;
        try
        {
            if (dblx == 0)
                throw dblx;
            stream << dblx;
            dblResult = (dbla - dblb * ic) / (dbld * dblx);
            stream << dblResult;
        }

        catch(double dblx)
        {
            cout << "Dividing by zero!!!";
        }


    } while (1);


    stream.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе надо завести два потока: input для чтения данных и output для вывода (естественно, это должны быть разные файлы).
Кроме того советую следующие правки:

- убрать `include <string>` (ты всё равно не пользуешься им);
- убрать `using namespace std;` и писать `std::cin`, `std::cout` и т.д.;
- убрать `void` из объявления `main`: в C++ это лишнее;
- не использовать `Sleep` и `system("pause")` и, соответственно, убрать `#include <windows.h>`. См. [Использование system("pause")](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44244/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-systempause)
- бесконечный цикл организовывать с помощью `for ( ; ; )`;
- заменить `try … catch` на `if …{ … exit … }`;
- если значение, присваиваемое dblResult, используется однократно, то сразу выводить его в поток, а переменную dblResult убрать;
- `return 0;` можно опустить: `main`возвращает 0 по умолчанию.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

А зачем же вы пытаетесь читать из файла, открытого на запись?
Файл после этого переходит в состояние ошибки и все дальнейшие действия с ним бессмысленны.