# Задержка окна в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Как воспроизвести задержку окна через настройки студии.
То есть альтернатива прописки system("pause") только без надобности писать это в коде.

Comment: `Ctrl-F5` жмите и получите желаемое. [Вопрос-побратим на en.so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1775870/5533854)

Comment: чел, программирование такая штука, где все надо писать. Как и StackOverFlow Надо хотябы написать какой ЯП! хоть я и понял что это c++

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Использование system("pause")](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44244/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-systempause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В первую очередь в установках вашего проекта `Linker -> System` поставить параметр `SubSystem` в значение `Console`. После этого при запуске без дебаггера (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>) окно консоли не будет закрываться само.
2. Начиная с VS2017 в настройках самой Visual Studio `Options -> Debugging -> General` появилась отдельная опция `Automatically close the console when debugging stops`. Если выключить эту опцию, то окно консоли не будет закрываться само и при запуске под дебаггером (<kbd>F5</kbd>).

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/636995/182825