# C++ | Почему после команды "cin" приложение закрывается?

Tags: c++, mingw, ввод

> Правки вносить можно.

Не хотелось задавать такой странный вопрос, но я всё-же хочу писать на **C++**. Дело в том, что в моей программе объявляется переменная **num**(я просто ещё учу..) и после этого у пользователя спрашиваются данные ввода. `cin >> num;`. После того, как пользователь ввёл значение, по сути, программа должна вывести такую строчку:

> Num is |пользовательский ввод|

но она вместо этого - **закрывается**. Я пишу код в **JetBrains** **CLion**, и там в консоли всё работает как должно, но когда я открываю сам свой *.exe*-шник, то я ввожу данные и она **мигом** закрывается. Я использую компилятор **MinGW** если что, и 20 стандарт **C++**. И в конце я сделал страховку `cin.get();`, но она не помогает. Помогите, мой код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    cin >> num;

    cout << "Num is " << num << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Дополнения:

> Я проверил в консоли **JetBrains CLion**, и там похоже что, `cin.get()`; не видится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что программа завершается - что вы еще хотите? Она закончилась, окно закрылось, занавес опущен, зрители расходятся.

Почему закончилась? потому что в буфере ввода после чтения числа остается введенный вами Enter - который и читает `cin.get()`.

Этому эффекту посвящен целый вопрос - посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/834447/195342).

Некоторые предпочитают использовать

```
system("pause");
```

которая перед выводом надписи на экран чистит входной буфер. Но нормальное решение - просто запускать программу в консольном окне (окне командной строки), которое само по себе не закрывается по окончании запущенной из него программы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я смотрю просто курс на ютубе и там используется в конце `cin.get();`

Comment: Тогда перед ним нужно внимательно смотреть, что вводилось, и чистить буфер. Или просто чистить, не глядя :)

Comment: @A_Br2H, **крайне** вам рекомендую перестать писать `system("pause")`, `cin.get()`, `getchar()`, `getc()` или любые другие варианты — это в консольном приложении быть не должно. Чтобы решить проблему с закрыванием консоли есть два варианта: 1) открывайте приложение через командую строку; 2) описан [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/636995/185348) (возможно, вам придется адаптировать ответ под свою IDE).

Comment: @A_Br2H, если вам интересно, почему `system("pause")` — это плохо, то почитайте [вот эти ответы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).

Comment: @eanmos я так понимаю что в конце вот этого быть не должно. Спасибо, сейчас надо попробовать свою IDE настроить для консоли как в Visual Studio.